# How is empty string collection any different from other empty collections, which don’t cause an exception

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview

If *ObjectDataSource.SelectMethod = A* and if A() returns a single object of type O, then this object is wrapped in a one element IEnumerable collection and returned by the ODS.Select method

Thus, assuming *ODS.SelectMethod* points to method A(), then if A() returns a null , when called by ODS,  this null is ( I assume ) wrapped into one element IEnumerable collection and no exception is thrown. Similarly, if *ODS.SelectMethod* points to method B(), which returns a list of objects, and if B() returns an empty collection when called by ODS, then no exception is thrown.

But if a method would instead return ( when called by *ODS.Select* ) an empty string collection (*string[]*), then I’d get exception “*The data source for GridView did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns*”.  How is empty string collection any different from other empty collections, which don’t cause an exception?

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

If your GridView has `AutoGenerateColumns` set to `true`, it requires a sequence of objects which have bindable members, like a `DataRow`. The column autogenerator inspects the signature of the sequence passed in and knows how to handle a few various cases, such as a DataRow which has a collection of columns which can be inferred into a list of columns on the GridView control. A string has no such properties. Set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false`, and define your own column, like so:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate><%# Container.DataItem %></ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

A string is pretty limited as a datasource for a GridView - unless you plan to eval properties about the string like it's Length, you can really just print the string itself (`DataItem`).

Comment: I don't quite understand how all that relates to the fact that when string[] doesn't contain any string objects, an exception is thrown, but if a List<> is empty (thus doesn't contain any objects to which gridView's rows could be data bound ), then no exception is thrown?

Comment: @Care it still tries to generate the columns, just no rows.